# Update workCloud data - amcharts

Tags: javascript, html, amcharts4

With static data the word cloud works fine.
When the data change and I update html, the cloud doesn't update.

This is my code in HTML

```
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../wordCloud.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">wordcloud(myData)</script>
```

This is How I initialize the chart

```
function wordcloud(myData) {        
    am4core.ready(function () {    
        // Themes begin
        am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
        am4core.useTheme(am4themes_kelly);
        // Themes end

        var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4plugins_wordCloud.WordCloud);
        chart.fontFamily = "Courier New";

        var series = chart.series.push(new am4plugins_wordCloud.WordCloudSeries());
        series.randomness = 0.1;
        series.rotationThreshold = 0.5;
        series.angles = [0];

        series.data = myData;

        series.dataFields.word = "tag";
        series.dataFields.value = "count";

        series.heatRules.push({
            "target": series.labels.template,
            "property": "fill",
            "min": am4core.color("#0000CC"),
            "max": am4core.color("#CC00CC"),
            "dataField": "value"
        });

        series.labels.template.tooltipText = "{word}: {value}";

        var hoverState = series.labels.template.states.create("hover");
        hoverState.properties.fill = am4core.color("#FF0000");

        var title = chart.titles.create();
        title.text = "Most frequent words in corpus";
        title.fontSize = 20;
        title.fontWeight = "800";

    });
}
```

Users can use a button to have more or less words displayed in the tag cloud. 
The new data is then calculated in the back end. But how can I update the cloud? 
Thanks for any help.

**Edit:**

I read the documentation and also read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57710540/update-am4charts-xychart-data). But this is not helping me because the difference btw. word cloud and chart is that the data are added via `series` variable and not the `chart` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The same update rules mentioned in the linked thread apply to series-level data - replacing the array, calling [`addData`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/series/#addData_method) or updating in place with [`invalidateRawData`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/series/#invalidateRawData_method) (both of which have series-level methods) will enable you to update the WordCloud. Your code seems to have the same limitation as the previous thread's code where you don't have access to the chart variable outside of your method, so I'm not seeing how you would exactly update that instance without making similar changes.

Basic demo below using a button that sets a new data array on the series:

```js
var myData = [{
  'tag': 'Yes',
  'count': 50
}, {
  'tag': 'No',
  'count': 50
}, {
  'tag': 'Maybe',
  'count': 50
}]

am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4plugins_wordCloud.WordCloud);
chart.fontFamily = "Courier New";

var series = chart.series.push(new am4plugins_wordCloud.WordCloudSeries());
series.randomness = 0.1;
series.rotationThreshold = 0.5;
series.angles = [0];

series.data = myData;

series.dataFields.word = "tag";
series.dataFields.value = "count";

series.heatRules.push({
  "target": series.labels.template,
  "property": "fill",
  "min": am4core.color("#0000CC"),
  "max": am4core.color("#CC00CC"),
  "dataField": "value"
});

series.labels.template.tooltipText = "{word}: {value}";

var hoverState = series.labels.template.states.create("hover");
hoverState.properties.fill = am4core.color("#FF0000");

var title = chart.titles.create();
title.text = "Most frequent words in corpus";
title.fontSize = 20;
title.fontWeight = "800";


document.getElementById('change').addEventListener('click', function() {

  series.data = [{
    'tag': 'Yes',
    'count': 50
  }, {
    'tag': 'No',
    'count': 50
  }, {
    'tag': 'Maybe',
    'count': 50
  }, {
    'tag': 'Sorta',
    'count': 50
  }, {
    'tag': 'Kinda',
    'count': 50
  }]
})
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/plugins/wordCloud.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<button id='change'>Change data</button>
```